# Is it possible to use AWS Lambda to connect to an external postgresql database?

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I am currently using Spring-boot to access an API that is able to change data within an postgresql database hosted on my machine. I would like to upload the program to AWS Lambda and use lambda for queries. Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible provided you have networking set up from AWS to external PostgreSQL with permissions allowed. It would be very slow and you'll pay money for outgoing traffic from AWS. Considering the latency you always have to be within the boundaries of lambda time which is 15 minutes. To be frank the path would be so troublesome you might not wanna do that.

Answer (score 1):

An AWS Lambda function that is *not* connected to an Amazon VPC has full access to the Internet. So, if the database is accessible on the Internet, then the Lambda function would be able to access it.

If you wish to add additional security by restricting the IP address range that is allowed to access the database, you can place the Lambda function in a **private subnet**, then use a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance in a public subnet. Attach a static **Elastic IP address** to the NAT Gateway / NAT Instance and all requests from the Lambda function will come from that IP address.